# HA Proxy changing https to http in HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, haproxy, http-redirect

I'm trying to get the url by using the C#.Net HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri behind a HA Proxy, but even if I enter **https://**app02.mywebsite.com.br/teste.aspx, I get **http://**app02.mywebsite.com.br/teste.aspx.

It changes from **https** to **http**, always.

If I do that without being behind if I can get the correct URL.

I'll appreciante if someone knows what happens, please!

Here is the code I'm using to test the issue.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%
    Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
%>
```

Here is my HA Proxy front-end config.

```
frontend main
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certificates/my-2023.pem
   mode http
   http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[hdr(X-Forwarded-For)]
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[hdr(X-Forwarded-For)]
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
   redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
   http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ Secure
   http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ HttpOnly
   http-response set-header X-Server %s
```

Thanks

---

Here is my full haproxy.cfg

```
global
   log 127.0.0.1 local0
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 664 level admin
   stats timeout 2m
   tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
   mode http
   monitor-uri /health_check
   log global
   option dontlognull
   option httplog
   option forwardfor
   option http-keep-alive
   timeout connect 2700s
   timeout client 2700s
   timeout server 2700s

listen stats
    bind :9000
    mode http
    balance
    timeout client 5s
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30s
    stats uri /haproxy_stats
    stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats admin if TRUE

frontend main
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certificates/efp-2023.pem
   mode http
   redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

   acl is_cf src -f /etc/haproxy/cf-ips-v4
   http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[hdr(X-Forwarded-For)] if !is_cf
   http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[hdr(cf-connecting-ip)] if is_cf

   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[hdr(X-Forwarded-For)]
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
   http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ Secure
   http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (.*) \1;\ HttpOnly
   http-response set-header X-Server %s

#############################
######### Frontends #########
#############################

## efp WS FrontEnd
  acl is_efp_uptime hdr_dom(Host) -i wsxnew.efp.com.br wsx.efp.com.br
  use_backend be_efp_uptime if is_efp_uptime

## efp SITE FrontEnd
  acl is_x_uptime hdr_dom(Host) -i xnew.efp.com.br x.efp.com.br x1.efp.com.br
  use_backend be_x_uptime if is_x_uptime

###########################
####### Backends ##########
###########################

## efp WS BackEnd
backend be_efp_uptime
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server app01 10.100.83.227:80 check

## efp SITE BackEnd
backend be_x_uptime
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server x01 10.100.83.227:80 check
```

Comment: `X-Forwarded-*` headers are not taken into consideration automatically, it appears. In ASP.NET Core [there's a middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that can be enabled but I assume you're on ASP.NET instead?

Comment: You may have a cookie that needs to be deleted.  You may of been using http when you first developed the code and then changed to https.  The cookie still remembers the http setting.

Comment: Yes, you're right mcont, I'm really using Asp.Net.

Comment: @jdweng, I don't think that's the case, because, for tests purpose, I created a direct DNS appointed to the same server to see what'd happen and realize that que https url returns correctly in the HttpContext.
I'll try now Aleksander's answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }` direct after `mode http`.

As you haven't put the backend and the **server line** into the output I assume haproxy is configured to speak http with the app. Because of that fact does the app not know that the orgin communication is done via https. as @mcont already mentioned you will need to tell the app that the client communication is done via https.

Print also the Header X-Forwarded-Proto and not only the uri and then will you see if the communication on haproxy site is done via https.

Comment: Hi, @Aleksandar!
Thank you so much, but moving the redirect did'nt work.
I put my full haproxy.cfg above. Maybe you can see more clearly the situation seeing the whole picture.

Comment: @VanderBatista have you read also the block below the redirect? The backend will always show **http** as haproxy is configured to talk via http to the backend. you have to check the **X-Forwarded-Proto** header to see if the frontend config is done via **https**